# Putting a box at the bottom of the poster with tikzposter

Tags: tikzposter

I have a poster in tikzposter.
Now I would like to place a box at the bottom of the page.
It should be as wide as the complete poster. 
It should "touch" both the sides of the poster and the bottom of the poster.
The box should not replace the title - I need that too.

How can this be done?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whole `tikzposter` is essentially one `tikzpicture`. Further, the class defines a  coordinate `bottomleft` at the lower left corner of the paper, so you could probably just add something like

```
\node [above right,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=\paperwidth,align=center,draw,fill=blue!30] at (bottomleft) {Some text at the bottom};
```

just before `\end{document}`.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[a0paper]{tikzposter}
\author{Someone}
\title{Something}
\begin{document}
\maketitle[width=0.95\textwidth,linewidth=0pt]
\node [above right,
       outer sep=0pt,
       minimum width=\paperwidth-2*\pgflinewidth,
       minimum height=7cm,
       align=center,font=\Huge,
       draw,fill=blue!30,
       ultra thick] at ([shift={(0.5*\pgflinewidth,0.5*\pgflinewidth)}]bottomleft) {Some text at the bottom};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!
This is exactly what I was looking for.
However, I would like to remove the line around the box. How can this be done?

Comment: @AaronWild remove `draw` and `ultra thick` from the node options. You can also remove `-2*\pgflinewidth` from the `minimum width`, and `[shift=...]` from the coordinate.