# Increase title block height tikzposter

Tags: posters, tikzposter

This problem is similar to this one: [Adjust block title height in tikzposter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/682864/adjust-block-title-height-in-tikzposter)

I want to make the area (height) around the title block larger so that I get more of the `BackgroundColour` before the actual poster block starts.

```
\documentclass[a0paper, landscape, 25pt, colspace=1cm, subcolspace=-1cm, blockverticalspace=1cm]{tikzposter} 
        \title{Title}
        \author{Person}
        \institute{Institute}
        \usetheme{Default}
    
        \definecolor{BackgroundColour}{RGB}{226,219,214}
        \colorlet{titlebgcolor}{BackgroundColour}
        
        \begin{document}
        \maketitle[
        
        \block{Block Title}{Test}
        
        \end{document}
```

How can I achieve this? Or can I just add a `\node` with the colours directly after the title block? Like this: [Putting a box at the bottom of the poster with tikzposter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309223/putting-a-box-at-the-bottom-of-the-poster-with-tikzposter). How can I then specify the position to be below the title, but before the first block?